# What could be some reasons to allow some run-time exceptions to fall through?

Tags: vb.net, initialization, declaration

For example, one could avoid a possible run-time null exception in the case below by instantiating `s` as it is declared. For example, `Dim s as String = ""` Is there a reason for  us to allow the possibility of a run-time exception? Perhaps it does not make sense for `s` to be `""`? This is not a homework question. I am just curious.

```
Public Function X() As String 
    Dim s as String 
    Dim sMethod As String = X 
    Try 
        Dim vowels() As String = {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u"}
        For Each vowel As String In vowels
            s = "0"
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception 
        Throw System.Exception(ex)
    End Try
    Return s 
End Function
```

- Editing to throw exception

Visual Studio seems to be smart enough to tell us that "A null reference exception could result at runtime." which means some capable, professional developers ignored this warning. This leads me to think that must be for a reason. The developers have since moved on though so I can't ask them. It might be something fundamental that I can't understand. Please help me understand this if you will. (I can't be the only person wondering about this.)

Comment: The compiler isn't smart enough to discover that the "s" variable is always going to be assigned, even though it isn't being initialized.  Do *not* write Try/Catch statements like this, it will get you in deep trouble when your program misbehaves without any way to find out why.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @HansPassant. I am sorry but I don't fully understand you. Could you please elaborate further?

Comment: @RBarryYoung: a `String` variable gets value of `Nothing`, if not initialized. So you *can* get an exception.

Comment: @Neolisk: Really?  Please show me the code that demonstrates such an exception.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - How about this code:  
Sub Main
    Dim s As String
    
    If s.StartsWith("A") Then
        Console.WriteLine(s)
    End If
End Sub   When I run this, I get a null ref exception when calling the StartsWith method.  This would not happen if the string were implicitly set to ""

Comment: @Chris Dunaway: Ah, I see.  VB and many CLR functions coerce the null to an empty string, but some (like StartsWith()) do not.  Very good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you don't initialize your `String` variable. And there goes some processing. In the end you expect get a definitive value, which you return via a `Return` statement. If, for some reason, you forgot to account for a possible execution path, VS will warn you about possible null-reference exception. Then you may think to yourself: "oh yeah, how did I forget that?"

For example, you have a `Function` that converts a `Integer` into a word (limited practical use, so consider it just for demo purposes):

```
Function ConvertIntToWord(a As Integer) As String
  Dim retString As String
  If a = 0
    retString = "Zero  "
  ElseIf a = 1
    retString = "One  " 
  End If
  Return retString
End Function
```

In the above lines, you were unlucky to forget about the `Else` path. Then suppose you want to run further processing on a resulting string:

```
ConvertIntToWord(5).TrimEnd
```

With 5 passed as an argument, you will get an exception at this point. If you instead listened to VS, you would have noticed a warning - underlined `retString` in `Return retString` line. So you could fix this problem without running your code.

Now suppose you initialize `Dim retString As String = ""`. You will no longer see the warning, and have to debug your program to solve this issue. Depending on the complexity of your program, it may take much more effort.

Bottom line - it is always better to spot problems in compile time, rather than run-time.

**EDIT:** Forgetting to initialize a variable can be intentional, for example why using [TryGetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx). For this method, value `is passed uninitialized`, according to documentation. However, VS does not know about this, so it will continue to show a warning, until you explicitly assign it to `Nothing`:

```
Dim retString As String = Nothing
```

So this is a way to tell VS that yes, you know it is uninitialized, but for this particular scenario, it is intentional.

Comment: World you ever see the error and say " yes, this time it was intentional"?

Comment: @Onwuka: if it answers your question, you can also mark it as accepted answer, to let other members of SO know your original issue has been addressed.

Comment: Thanks for reminding. So in a situation like the one I had (where I don't think I need to pass it uninitialized), there is no need to leave it, right?

Comment: @Onwuka: purpose of your code is not quite clear to me. Why would you assign a method to `sMethod` string variable? Why do you catch an exception, if it possibly cannot happen there? Also your catch clause is invalid. Still, from what I can see `s` will always be returned as `0`. However, VS is not smart enough to analyse execution path and figure that out. In this case you need to override with `Dim s As String = Nothing`, to show you are okay with it. Generally, you need to make sure you have no warnings (rather than just no errors).